# How to get the previous and next record based on creation date and group by another column in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, aggregate, min

Taking example I have a table similar to the below one,

```
+----+--------------+------------+-------+
| id | date_col     | label      | tag   |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+
| 1  | 2010-09-07   | Record 1   | 810   |
| 2  | 2010-09-03   | Record 2   | 810   |
| 3  | 2010-08-23   | Record 3   | 811   |
| 4  | 2010-08-23   | Record 4   | 809   |
| 5  | 2010-08-23   | Record 5   | 810   |
| 6  | 2010-08-12   | Record 6   | 809   |
| 7  | 2010-08-06   | Record 7   | 811   |
| 8  | 2010-08-06   | Record 8   | 809   |
| 9  | 2010-08-02   | Record 9   | 810   |
| 10 | 2010-08-01   | Record 10  | 811   |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+
```

Is there a way by which I can get the `date_col` data before and after a specific date like `2010-08-23` according to a specific tag like `810`, in a single query.

So that I can get `2010-08-02` and `2010-09-03` i.e. `Record 9` and `Record 2` as a result.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`/`lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(date_col) over (partition by tag order by date) as prev_date,
             lead(date_col) over (partition by tag order by date) as next_date
      from t
      where tag = 810
     ) t
where '2010-08-23' in (prev_date, next_date);
```

You have no examples of duplicate tags on the same date, so I assume that is not possible.  If that is possible, you need a slightly more complicated solution.

To handle duplicate tags, you can use cumulative `max()`/`min()` with window frames:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             max(date_col) over (partition by tag order by date rows between unbounded preceding and interval 1 day preceding) as prev_date,
             min(date_col) over (partition by tag order by date rows between interval 1 following and unbounded following) as next_date
      from t
      where tag = 810
     ) t
where '2010-08-23' in (prev_date, next_date);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Yes duplicate tags on the same date can possible. If this is going to more complex will it be more costly?

Comment: @Sinha . . . Naww.  It just requires more typing.